# The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am using FB like button on my webpage, sometimes it render and sometimes its not, When I see console for Error Log it showing error

```
The "fb-root" div has not been created, auto-creating
```

in all.js
I am using this code

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>
<script>    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=105911812857824";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    } (document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>


<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true">
                    </div>
```

Comment: It is working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ES3wv/)

Comment: I works fine sometimes but sometimes it not show the button

Comment: same problem. (with Turbolinks)

Comment: when it does not please show the console for loading errors maybe a time out issue.

Answer (score 7):

Use this following code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=694586437259261&version=v2.0";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and also put this code also

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

You have to provide data-href="your link for like" that will  work for you.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [newer way to initialize the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart/v2.3).

You can put the `appId` in the init method instead of embedded in the URL.

They don't even suggest you use `fb-root` anymore. In fact I don't really see why you ever needed to. You'll still get a warning in the console but I don't see any reason to worry about putting it in manually.

```
<script>

   window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
       appId      : 'your-app-id',
       xfbml      : true,
       version    : 'v2.3'
     });
   };

   (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Comment: Now they don't even show a warning in the console. The `<div id="fb-root"></div>` requirement has been removed from their documentation. It can be safely removed.